# How it's possible, to set unique style for each element in a node collection in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i want is, to get a collection of nodes, then, with a for loop, set for an example the left style property to `left: "-" + element.offsetWidth + px"`. I'm thinking a lot for the solution, but what complicates the problem is that i want to remove the property when an event occurs (for an example: hover), and return to the style what is preset in the stylesheet. I think, the solution is in classes, because with `element.style.left` i need to define the `element.style.left` again when the event occurs. But that's not what i want. With a pre-defined class in the stylesheet is also not what i want, because i can't set an always changing variable to the value of `left`. What is an interesting, but i think not the most elegant solution is, to get each element, create an uniqe class for them, and set the class's style, then add the class to the element, and remove it when the event occurs. Creating as many classes as many elements we have. But how it's possible? Or what's the best solution for the problem?

Comment: You know what would help your question? Code, an example of what you've tried

Comment: I don't understand what you're hoping to gain from this question. You seem to have a good idea of changing styles, setting classes, and using JS to manipulate an element, so when you ask "how it's possible" I'm a little floored. You just explained how, right? Are you having a specific issue that's preventing you from what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an idea.
Don't need unique classes, and to get the element's width. CSS:

```css
.style{
position: relative;
transform: translateX(-100%);
left:0;
}
```

It works.